# Rails parameter passing issue despite console showing parameter correctly passed and controller correctly called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I am struggling on a **simple parameter passing issue** around simplified code for debugging purpose. I want to pass an apartment object to change one of its boolean attribute (show_email) from true to false using a custom controller

Here is the link in my view calling the hide_contact_email action in the apartment controller

```
 <%= link_to "Hide temporarily", apartment_hide_contact_email_path(apartment), method: :put %>
```

Here is the simplified controller apartments_controller.rb where I just want to see the passed apartment_id

```
def hide_contact_email
  #I want to check what I get in the console
  puts apartment_id
  redirect_to landlord_dashboard_path
end
```

The console give me an **undefined variable error**.

```
Started PUT "/apartments/61/hide_contact_email" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-10 10:35:11 +0800
        Processing by ApartmentsController#hide_contact_email as HTML
          Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"acsMqJMWR6rM9ooAzmhXKEJVP1HimENQpSMt1SrP3jZBWFxktNk5BI1rhu8BjN8zAdk93+0ksLTa63/YgOnyTQ==", "apartment_id"=>"61"}
        Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2141ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 185548)
        NameError (undefined local variable or method `apartment_id' for #<ApartmentsController:0x000055acd9351868>
        Did you mean?  apartment_url):  
        app/controllers/apartments_controller.rb:54:in `hide_contact_email'
```

I am confused how come I get an undefined local variable apartment_id where the console clearly states that 1) the right controller is called (**Processing by ApartmentsController#hide_contact_email**) and 2) the parameter has been passed (**apartment_id =>"61"**). Thank you.

Comment: Why would you expect the local variable to be defined in the first place? You access parameters through the params hash - `params[:apartment_id]`.

Comment: You are very right. I was confused on how to access parameter with the params hash. I tried other wrong syntax such as params[:apartment] that got me confused. Thank you! I am good now.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will automatically load your parameters into the params hash, which you can access as you would normally. So for example, if you are sending this JSON content:

{ "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }

Your controller will receive params[:company] as { "name" => "acme", "address" => "123 Carrot Street" }.

You can access parameters through params hash i.e: params[:apartment_id].

for further reference you can check rails guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.